# Exclude a folder name from Eclipse file search

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I exclude a certain folder name from the Eclipse file search (`CTRL + H`)?  For example if I want to search all files, but exclude any files in a folder called `FolderName` (and its subdirectories), what can I enter in the file name pattern to accomplish this?

Comment: Seems like you can't do this in eclipse.  I was expecting to the same thing but have no luck. And finally I used the method same as Kevin k provided.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have a couple options for you.

**First Option**

If it is feasible, select the range of folders you want to search, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - click any folders you want to exclude from the search.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>H</kbd> to open file search, then under `Scope` choose the `Selected Resources` option.

**Second Option**

Right-click the folder to exclude, select properties, check `Derived`, and apply.  This works because by default File Search will exclude derived resources.  After the search you can undo the `Derived` setting.

Note that I'm not familiar enough with the inner workings of Eclipse to be certain about potential side effects of temporarily marking files as derived like this, but I suspect it should be okay.

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for but thank you for your answer Kevin; I'll keep these in mind for an alternative options.

Comment: The second option worked like a charm for me.  Prior to doing this, Eclipse's search would pop-up with errors on some bin/ files I had in my project structure.  Setting this bin/ folder to "Derived" cleared that right up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

After more digging, I found yet another workaround which might be helpful for anyone with this same issue.

- Project > Properties > Resource > Resource Filter
- Add

  - In Filter type, check "Exclude all"
  - In Applies to, check "Folders" and "All children (recursive)"
  - File and Folder Attributes, select "Name" "matches" and enter the folder name you want to exclude in the text field.

Comment: Seems the best option, except if you have a lot of projects,....
It also can be done with "Location" attribute.
Source: http://blog.chmouel.com/2010/06/17/exclude-git-or-svn-directories-in-eclipse-helios/

Answer (score 4):

You can define a Working Set that includes just the directories you want to search. In the File Search dialog, select **Working Set** in the **Scope** section (at the bottom), then **Choose...**, then use **New...** to define your Working Set.